# How to programatically load data into big query tables without using files?

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to start a load job into BigQuery tables and specify the data to be loaded as a string or a stream. I can only find APIs which point to Google Cloud Storage Files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not currently possible to directly stream individual records into BigQuery - data loading is based on batch operations of source files.

It is possible to directly send data to an API endpoint ([via POST request](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/import?hl=en#localimport)), without first staging it in Google Cloud Storage. However, I would suggest using Google Cloud storage for various reasons, including better reliability for loading very large files, as well as having an archive of your source data in our Cloud.